# Ionic Native HTTP Client delete function not works, it doesn’t send the parameters

Tags: http, ionic3

I’m trying to do a delete request to my api but it returns that the parameters are missing:

```
this.http.delete(path, data,headers)
.then(response => {
return JSON.parse(response.data);
})
.catch(error => {return this.handleError(error)});
```

It seems that delete function not sends the body data. **The same request with postman works fine.**
With post, and put there are not problems, What would be the problem?

Info:

```
Android platform: 6.4.0
Ionic version 3.9.2
Ionic native http: 4.5.3
Http Plugin version: 1.11.0
```

Comment: Any luck? I am also facing the same problem